# How to write this query please help me out

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms, database

Assuming you have the following four tables;

- customers
- orders
- ordered_items
- items

Orders contains a foreign key (customer_id) referencing the customer who placed the order. Each ordered_item contains a foreign key (order_id) referencing the overall order, as well as an item_id referencing the items table. How would you write a single SQL query that returns a single row for each customer, which includes a column containing their total number of orders (including any customers with 0 orders), and a list of unique item SKU’s (items.sku) from the items table?

Comment: Looks like a homework. What have you tried?

Comment: I have been asked this thing in an Interview. I am not so proficient in SQL so just trying to figure out the answer.

Comment: @KattangooriReddy Now is time to learn some SQL then, I suppose. Then you'll be able to confidently answer this sort of question on subsequent interviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To get a single row for each customer, you will need to group by customer_id;
- To be able to list all their orders, you need to link from the customer to the order - this needs to be an outer join, to include customers with 0 orders;
- To be able to list all item SKUs that the customer has ever ordered, you need to link via the ordered_items table to the items table; you also need to use the MySQL function `group_concat`, to be able to summarise these on a single line.

So:

```
select c.customer_id, 
       count(distinct o.order_id) distinct_orders,
       group_concat(distinct i.sku) ordered_item_skus
from customers c
left outer join orders o on c.customer_id = o.customer_id
left outer join order_items oi on o.order_id = oi.order_id
left outer join items  i on oi.item_id = i.item_id
group by c.customer_id
```